# Purpose of $db_adapter->prepare();

Tags: zend-framework

What is the purpose of `$db_adapter->prepare()` in Zend Framework 1?

Here is the sample code:

```
$db_adapter->prepare($sqlstring);
```

Here `$sqlstring` is the variable that stores the MySQL select query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`prepare` in ZF1 adapters is the same as [prepare in PDO](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php). It prepares the given sql string for its execution in the context of a prepared statement.

Comment: Thanks **Thomas**. Now i had an idea on what the prepare() do.